# Delete linked list function does not match all test case

Tags: c++, linked-list

Could anyone enlighten me on why doesn't my resize function delete the node at the end of the linked list? Sorry if my code is unnecessarily long.

For this series of code, I am supposed to resize the list to contain `n` elements. If `n` is smaller than the current size, then keep only the first `n` elements, then destroy those beyond. If `n` is larger than the current size, the new elements are initialized as `val`.

My output:
`-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2 -2` (7 nodes)

Desired output:
`-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -2` (6 nodes)

```
void list::resize(int n, int val) {

    int count = 0;

    int count1 = n;
    if (the_list == nullptr) {
       // handling of case when list is empty
        }
    } else {
        node *p = the_list;
        node *pc = the_list;
        while (p->next != nullptr) {
            p = p->next;
            count++;
        }
        if (n < count) {    
            if (n== 0) {
               //if n==0, delete the all of the nodes in the linked list
                }
            } else {
                while (count1!= 1) {
                    pc=pc->next;
                    count1--;
                }
                if (pc->next->next == nullptr) {
                    delete pc;
                    pc->next = nullptr;
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count-n+1; i++) {
                        node *nxt = pc->next->next; 
                        delete pc->next;
                        pc->next = nxt;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // handling of case where code is required to add nodes with a special value
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{

std::string funcName[6] = 
                        {"Push_Front          ",
                         "Erase One Element   ",
                         "Erase Some Elements ",
                         "Resize w New Val    ",
                         "Resize w Default Val",
                         "Merge               "};

int choice, listID = 0, pos1, pos2, newSize, newVal;
CS170::list list1, list2;
CS170::list *chosenList;

do
{
    std::cin >> choice;
    if (choice != 0 && choice != 6)
    {
        std::cin >> listID;
    }

    if (choice != 0)
    {
        std::cout << funcName[choice-1] << ": ";

        if (listID == 1)
            chosenList = &list1;
        else
            chosenList = &list2;

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                std::cin >> newVal;
                chosenList->push_front(newVal);
                break;

            case 2:
                std::cin >> pos1;
                chosenList->erase(pos1);
                break;

            case 3:
                std::cin >> pos1 >> pos2;
                chosenList->erase(pos1, pos2);
                break;

            case 4:
                std::cin >> newSize >> newVal;
                chosenList->resize(newSize, newVal);
                break;

            case 5:
                std::cin >> newSize;
                chosenList->resize(newSize);
                break;

            case 6:
                list1.sort();
                list2.sort();
                list1.merge(list2);
                break;
        }

        if( is_circular( list1 ) || 
            is_circular( list2 ) )
        {
          std::cin.sync();
          std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
          std::cout << "List is invalid (circular), test exiting" << std::endl;
          return 0;
        }

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
                std::cout << "List" << listID << " (" << std::setw(2) << 
                    chosenList->size() << " nodes): ";
                chosenList->print_list();
                break;

            case 6:
                std::cout << "\n";
                std::cout << "List1" << " (" << std::setw(2) << 
                    list1.size() << " nodes): ";
                list1.print_list();

                std::cout << "List2" << " (" << std::setw(2) << 
                    list2.size() << " nodes): ";
                list2.print_list();
                break;
        }
    }
}
while (choice != 0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your code is so unnecessarily long that you are aware of it, then please spend more work on making a more M [mcve]. Maybe you can show only the delete function, the main function and a hardcoded filler function to set up a list which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This is a "why does this code not work?" question. This kind of question is required to provide a [mcve]. My previous comment mentions that the shown code, by your own statement, is not M. This is more about not being V and not even C. Please add a `main()` function which serves to demonstrate the problem with suitable data.

Comment: Make an output function, which outputs the values in the list. Call that function at each step of your resize function. Add a lot of "debug N", outputs at each step of our resize function, with N being unique numbers, allowing you to always know where/what is going on when. Fill your array with unique numbers, so that you always know which of the original entries are still there. Then show a MCVE with those changes. Alternatively do a debug session with a suitable debugger tool for your environmen.t

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice! i've added the main function. Is it ok or is there anything else i should do?

Comment: See my previous comment, it is quite some work... Consider deleting the question temporarily, while working on improving it. When you are satisfied, undelete it again.

Comment: Review for formatting, your main is not code-formatted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Alright. thanks man.

Comment: Also, while adding a main is very good, please spend some time on making the MCVE more Minimal. Finding out which parts can be deleted without changing the behaviour is very helpful information for finding the error and it makes for a more convenient work with your question. You can delete parts and replace them by comments, e.g. `// handling of special case of empty list deleted for brevity.... `. If it is not used in your problem case, then it is not a shortcoming of your question.

Comment: Ohh i c! okok. Will go and do that.

Comment: very new to this platform.

Comment: We cannot have a slightest idea what's wrong with your program because you didn't post your program. You posted a random fragment of it. Note making a [mcve] doesn't mean "delete lines from your code until it fits on the screen". You need to pay attention to C and V, not just M.